# loop through javascript returns error

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to run the following function in javascript and I keep getting "The server tag is not well formed" error.

```
function CreateRow() {      
  var NumRows = document.getElementById('txtNumRows');
  looping(NumRows.value);      
}

function looping(numLoops) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= numLoops; i++) {
    alert(i);
  }
}
```

I have a textbox that a user will enter how my employees they want to add and then I want to loop through a function I have that will create client side textboxes.  I assume this is a simple answer but I searched stackoverflow and google and couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: Your error isn't in here. It's to do with either HTML or XML not being well formed. And it's telling you it's the <server> tag. What that is in your code, I don't know. You may have to post some more of your code or take a look to see what that is.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  I moved these 2 functions to the end right before the closing script tag and now it is working.  Is position of the function something that I have to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I moved these 2 functions to the end right before the closing script tag and now it is working.